# How to load UIView from UIViewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have created a `view` and now I want to load that `view` from another `viewcontroller` without allocating the `view`. Is it possible or not. please clarify me.

I am doing like following

1)Added `UIView` in viewcontroller.xib and given view class name for the `view`.

2)created IBOutlet for the `view` and connected.

Now I want to access one property of a `view` without allocating. Is it possible to do or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've created an IBOutlet and hooked up the view, then you are done. The view is allocated when the xib loads and the reference is placed in the IBOutlet. You can access the view and it's properties through that without doing any allocating yourself.

Answer (score 0):

When your view controller is loaded, your view connected to it (by IBOutlet) also gets loaded. In this case you have access to all view's property.

Look at "Looading up an XIB" section in this [article](http://wiki.oxygenelanguage.com/en/Working_with_.xib_Files).